# Linebreaks / newlines Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm creating some html using js by doing {{description| linebreaksbr}} and I keep getting unterminated string literal errors.

I know this is because JS doesn't like strings to be on different lines without a '\' but this code is used on a production server and it formats the string fine

```
+ '<p class="description">Complete the following riddle end location.<br /><br />Riddle Details:<br />The year Lincoln was born + The 17th digit of Pi.'
+ '</p>'
```

On my localhost however I am getting

```
+ '<p class="description">Complete the following riddle 
<br />
<br />Riddle Details:
<br />The year Lincoln was born + The 17th digit of Pi.'
+ '</p>'
```

The code is just

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var html = '<p class="description">{{description|linebreaksbr }}'
         + '</p>'
</script>
```

I recently just copied over all the data from the production server. Could it be a weird formatting that for newlines that django doesn't understand?

*** Found what was wrong
Not Sure what went wrong but I think it has to do with how pgadmin3 exports data. I exported the data to a text file and ran the sql to insert everything / create tables.

With the problematic data I just copied and pasted it into a text file, removed the new lines and re added them by pressing enter at the end of each and resaved the data into the database and it was fine.

Not entirely sure what was off

Comment: Where's the code? http://sscce.org/

Comment: Give us the HTML generated by the given snippet.

Comment: Updated to have exactly what is being produced by the JS and the template tags        @marcin I read over what should be posted and what is helpful and i have already provided what I was given along with what I believe the problem could be / where it is

Comment: Also, which version of django are you running in each case?

Comment: Both are using Django 1.3.1. Both in a virtual env and have the exact same installed features. Compared with pip freeze

Answer (score 0):

I bet it's an issue with line-terminators. Windows uses a two-character sequence; linux and mac use one. I guess in dev you're receiving a windows-terminated string, but for whatever reason your python setup expects single-char line terminators (perhaps you're running on cygwin)?